# If condition statement erroring "There are coding standard violations (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement

I am working on a customization where conditions are based on participant disability value "**Y**" and relation code child value "**C**".

**Build Error points to**: "There are coding standard violations" ;
Avoid using if statements without curly braces.

If client wants to display disability footnote on the page and dpnd is disable ; baseFtnt2 is the footnote  that needs show.

I believe the error is in the syntax:

```
if (dpndEvntBean.getHasDpndDsbl()
        && item.getDsblCd().trim().equals("Y")
        && ddb.getRltnCd().trim().equals("C"));
{
    ddb.addFtntIdListEntry("baseFtnt2");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. You will then immediately see such stuff. And, in this case, if you are using a style like `if (...) {` instead of `if (...) <newline> {` you would have spot the problem `if (...); {` far more easy.

Comment: Thank you Zabuza I will remember that next time.

Answer (score 3):

You should remove the `;` at the end of the 3th line

```
if (dpndEvntBean.getHasDpndDsbl()
        && item.getDsblCd().trim().equals("Y")
        && ddb.getRltnCd().trim().equals("C")) // Removed ';'
{
    ddb.addFtntIdListEntry("baseFtnt2");
}
```

otherwise it would mean

```
if (dpndEvntBean.getHasDpndDsbl()
        && item.getDsblCd().trim().equals("Y")
        && ddb.getRltnCd().trim().equals("C"))
{

}

{
    ddb.addFtntIdListEntry("baseFtnt2");
}
```

So an **empty block** for the `if` and the `ddb` call called **always**.

Comment: thanks Michael, so basically expressions don't require the ending ; only execution statements end in ; I am building the code now, should work now!

Comment: Good luck coding :-) .. and indeed ; is not used after if, while or for loops normally.